# How to make text block on image responsive?

Tags: html, css, image, text, responsive

I have created a text block on an image but when I check the site on iPad and iPhone the image stays ok, but the text moves.
How can I make this text responsive?

Link: http://test.preci-dental.be/home/

This is the code I used:

```
    <style>
.container {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Arial;

}

.text-block {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 95px;
  right: 740px;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.75;
  color: black;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <center><img src="http://test.preci-dental.be/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/helping-your-child-trust-the-dentist-1110x450-1024x415.jpg" alt="Nature" style="width:90%;"></center>
  <div class="text-block">
<h1 style="color:#749C91;">Preci-Dental</h1>
    <br><p style="color:black;">Welkom bij tandartspraktijk Preci-Dental. De groepspraktijk werd door Liesbeth en Karel opgericht in 2019 en is gevestigd in Bertem, gelegen tussen Leuven en Brussel. Bij Preci-Dental streven we naar moderne mondzorg op maat voor iedereen: precieze en persoonlijke service, gebaseerd op bewezen efficiënte en moderne technieken.</strong></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind on using media queries, i guess this should solve your problem:

PS: I used "!important" because i injected the code via plugin. Maybe is not needed in your case.

I'm also assuming you want the text area as 70% of your viewport width and 600px  as max-width in your media query. So, when your viewport width is smaller than 600px, the code will override your css for this selector.

About media queries: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .text-block {
    left: auto !important;
    right:auto !important;
    min-width:70vw;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, I added this code, but is only partially working. You can see it when you resize the screen in your computer brwoser as well. There is also a difference when the screen is horizontally or vertically orientated. How can I fix this?

Comment: I have also another very strange thing: when looking at the address, telephone and email on top and you start naviagtion from home to team there is a difference in the visuals of the text. How is this possible?